# Change View webform link edit to edit/all

Tags: views, webforms

I am currently using drupal 10 and I created a page using View (acquiring webform with pages). In View I add link edit webform.

When I click edit, it can open the submission as expected. However since the webform using pages, when I edit it opens page by page. There is a tab to see all pages, which is easier.

[image]

The different is edit and edit/all

Can I change the default to edit/all to open edit all pages.

Regards,
waluyo

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can find the solution.
a. Hide edit link and output as URL
[image]

b. Then I add custom text, and simply add the replacement token with /all. This link replaces the original edit link. I can use a nice edit icon as well.

[image]